# dir folders at a certain folder depth in a batch file

Tags: batch, cmd.exe, dir

I want, with a batch file, to be able to search and display the files in a bunch of folders called "error" located in a bunch of different places.

The error folder is always at the same folder depth but the folder names befor them is different.

```
dir /A-d /b C:\Temp\*random_folder_name*\*random_folder_name*\error
```

So, can I create a line that displays all the files in all the error folders, two folders "below", in this example "C:\Temp"? or do I have to add one dir line for every error-folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows 7 and later have power shell:

You can try:

```
Get-ChildItem \*\*\*
```

This returns all items with a depth of two subfolders. Adding * adds an additional subfolder to search in.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13249085/limit-get-childitem-recursion-depth

Answer (score 3):

Here is a relatively simple, but inefficient solution using FINDSTR with a regular expression. I use `[\\]` to match `\` because of an inconsistency on Vista.

```
@echo off
dir /b /s c:\temp\*|findstr /rix "c:[\\]temp[\\][^\\]*[\\][^\\]*[\\]error[\\][^\\]*"
```

Here is a more complicated, but very efficient solution using multiple FOR statements.

```
@echo off
for /d %%A in (c:\temp\*) do for /d %%B in ("%%A\*") do for %%C in ("%%B\error\*") do echo %%C
```

Comment: Isn't there a missing `/d` in the most inner loop?

Comment: @miroxlav - Definitely not. The OP was looking for ***files*** three levels deep, so there should be no `/d` when listing the error folder contents. The question title is confusing, but the question body clearly asks for files within that folder.

Answer (score 0):

Windows has built-in alternatives to grep: `find` and `findstr`.

`findstr` will support a regular-expression (you can get more info by typing `help findstr`), but you will be somewhat limited by the output of `dir` which doesn't seem to support relative listings ...

```
dir /A-d /S /B | findstr /B /R /I /X "C:\\Temp\\[^\\]*\\[^\\]*\\error\\.*"
```

Comment: That regex will not work because `.*` can match any number of \

Comment: sorry, that was a silly mistake by me, please review my update.

Answer (score -1):

You could install the [GNU Win32](http://getgnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) libraries and use [grep](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep) for this:

```
dir /b /s *.*|grep "error\\[^\\]*$"
```

The suggested way to install them is with [getgnuwin32](http://getgnuwin32.sourceforge.net/).

BTW, if you just wanted to see text files it'd be like this:

```
dir /b /s *.txt|grep "error\\[^\\]*$"
```

If you would like to ensure that only folders at a certain depth are used then it's a little more complicated:

```
dir /b /s *.*|grep "^\([^\\]*\\\)\{7\}error\\[^\\]*$"
```

This will only display results where the error directory is seven directories deep (from the root directory).

Comment: Are you sure? That last regex looks incorrect. Why are you escaping `(`, `)`, `{`, and `}`?

Comment: Yes I'm sure I've actually tested all of these on my system. Trust me, those characters need escaped. It won't work without it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm used to using JavaScript regex. That is a very curious design choice for grep. Most meta characters are escaped if you want to treat them as a literal. But in grep, some literal characters are "escaped" to turn them into meta characters. That is crazy!

Comment: That gave me an idea: https://gist.github.com/krowe/da2a6b021ac891f8e3be

Comment: Yes, hybrid scripting is a powerful way to extend batch capabilities. I have created a different but related JScript/batch utility called [REPL.BAT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16735079/1012053). It has been incredibly useful for many problems that are difficult to solve with pure batch.

Comment: I hadn't realized that you wrote that. I've used that before as well and only a few moments ago realized that it was using the same technique.